# Oracle Reports Rounded Corner Image

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, rounded-corners, oraclereports

I have an image in my report. I want to use rounded corner image format. (Because now my frame is square so corners appear black) How can I use that? ( My details shown in the image. )

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, as far as I can tell. Images are rectangular.

What you could do is to edit the image itself - create a white rectangle and paste current image onto it so that currently black corners turn into white. Then, when you insert such an image, it'll look OK in the report.

Comment: Thank you.. As you can see in the image while top corners are on gray background, lower corners are on blue background.

Comment: You're welcome. If image is set to be displayed on background(s) that aren't white (or any other color you can use in what I described), then it'll be more complex. Perhaps you'll have to do it in several steps, corner by corner, color by color. Use colorpicker (many browsers offer it as an add-on) to find EXACTLY which color it is. Good luck!

Comment: How can I set color corner by corner? I can set color of only rectangle, can't I?

Comment: Yes, but you'd - in a program capable of editing images, such as MS Paint - create one large rectangle (which covers the whole image size) and add 4 separate rectangles (one for each corner) which is painted to color you need.